# Escape Ampersand in batch file and URL encoding

Tags: batch-file, cmd, tableau-api

URL Resolves the %26 to & on tabcmd call and making it to the wrong URL

my batch file is as follows :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set str=%1
set str=!str:^&=%%26!
set var1=!str!
set var1=!var1: =%%20!

set var2=!var1!
set var2=!var2:,=!

tabcmd get "views/tableau_workbook/first_page.png?status=O&category=ALL&cust=!var1!&:size=1715,893" -f "D:\myfolder\!var2!\!var2!_1.png" --no-certche


pause
```

For example : 
I am passing in the parameter "A & B" to the batch file.
var1 variable has the following value before calling the URL : 
A%20%26%20B ,which is expected.

Once its calling the URL, the URL is resolved to **A%20&%20B**  but instead I am trying to get **A%20%26%20B**

I even tried replacing the `&` by `%25%26` to make it `%26` on the URL upon execution but dint help.

Could some one help out resolve this. Thanks !

Comment: Try quoting all assignments: `set "str=something"` (note the opening quote position).

Comment: Where the batch end, It's hard to reproduce, can you simplify the example please :) ? like: usage: `fake-command "A & B"` code: `@echo %1`

Comment: If my answer below was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted.  If not, then could you provide some feedback of what didn't meet your approval?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't find any other solutions, you could always borrow JavaScript's `encodeURIComponent` string method by way of a JScript hybrid.  Save this with a .bat extension and give it a shot.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:Jscript "%~f0" "%~1"') do set "%%I"

set var2=!var1:%%2C=!

tabcmd get "views/tableau_workbook/first_page.png?status=O&category=ALL&cust=!var1!&:size=1715,893" -f "D:\myfolder\!var2!\!var2!_1.png" --no-certche

pause
goto :EOF

@end // end batch / begin JScript hybrid chimera
WSH.Echo('var1=' + encodeURIComponent(WSH.Arguments(0)));
```